# Use javascript to insert data from site A into forms in site B

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

Site A is a database of various academic papers, and site B is a database of bib data of various academic data.

I know how, using javascript and greasemonkey, to get and format whatever data I like from site A (e.g., authors, title, submission date, etc). I would like to take a subset of that data and submit it to the forms on site B.

Site B includes inputs like this:

```
<input name="au" size="40" value="">
```

Various references suggest things like

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

Which don't work. The webpage doesn't have anything like

```
<form id="myForm"...
```

Though it does have

```
<form method="post" action="/partOfUrl">
```

Things like

```
document.getElementsByName("au").value = "authorName";
```

or

```
document.getElementsByName("au").post = "authorName";
```

don't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName` returns an array of elements, even if there is only one... so to edit the value of a field try `document.getElementsByName("au")[0].value = "authorName";`. jQuery offers a nice form handling system you could use to submit the form, or you could fire a click event on the submit button for the form rather than calling the submit handler directly

Comment: Thanks! I have a followup question -- how do I fire a click event? It looks like .click() or .onclick() should work, but I can't get it to. The web code looks like <input value="Search" name="Search" type="submit">, and document.getElementsByName("Search")[0].onclick(); didn't work.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("Search")[0].click();` *should* work